# Import text file into database

Tags: php, mysql, file, import, phpmyadmin

Is it possible to import a text file with phpmyadmin?

In the file is this:

```
country - county / city
USA - Florida / Orlando
USA - Florida / Miami
USA - Washington / Washington DC
Switzerland - Solothurn / Grenchen
```

The file has over 3000 lines

Now i want to import to my catergory table
the table is like this:

```
id | parent_id | name
```

The country and county is in the file several times. In my database i need it only once.
City is in the file unique

Can i make this with phpmyadmin or is it only possible with php?
Can anybody tell me how to do this.
Thanks

Comment: You can use fread() to read from file line by line and explode your string to get the filed you need for your db.

Comment: Should the line "USA - Florida / Orlando" result in 3 rows with name "USA", "Florida" and "Orlando" or should it be one row with name "USA - Florida / Orlando"? In case of first option should the parent_id be inserted with a proper value (USA is parent_id of Florida and Florida is parent_id of Orlando) ?

Comment: no in my database it should be 3 rows

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to do it directly with phpmyadmin. I see @Mattia's suggestion as valuable, even if I'd consider looping through with a regex line per line then associating values.

Comment: thanks for the help. i have edited the question with my actual code

Answer (score 1):

phpMyAdmin can help with this, but you'll have to massage the data with another program so that you use the same delimiter (either `-` or `/` should be fine). You can do this with "search and replace" inany text editor (or your favorite command-line tool; sed, awk, perl, etc). Just make sure your *data* doesn't contain the character you're replacing (for instance, in "Saxony-Anhalt").

Then you can do a standard import from the phpMyAdmin "Import" tab. It looks like you'll want to use the following parameters:

- Columns separated with: `/` or `-` (based on what you select above)
- Columns enclosed with: (blank)
- Columns escaped with: (blank)
- Lines terminated with: `auto`

Comment: after a few minutes or hours of thinking abaout 
i mean with phpmyadmin is this not possible because by the state and city i must add the parent_id

Comment: Oh, since it wasn't in your text file I assumed it was an auto increment primary key.

Comment: Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own solution

```
<?php
require 'funcs/connect.php';

$file = 'cities.txt';

$file_handle = fopen($file, 'r');

while (!feof($file_handle)) {

$line = fgets($file_handle);

$text_line = explode("-",$line);

echo $text_line[0];  
echo $text_line[1];
echo $text_line[2];


if ($text_line[1] != "")
        {
            $name = $text_line[1];
            $stmt = $handler->prepare("SELECT name FROM news_cat WHERE name = '$name'");
                $stmt->execute();
                $count = $stmt->rowCount(); 
                if ($count >= 1)
                {
                    echo"Kanton schon vorhanden";
                }
                else
                {
                $stmt = $handler->prepare("INSERT INTO news_cat(name,parent_id)VALUES('$name','0')");
                $stmt->execute();   
                }
        }

if ($text_line[2] != "")
        {
            $name = $text_line[2];
            $canton = $text_line[1];
            $stmt = $handler->prepare("SELECT name FROM news_cat WHERE name = '$name'");
                $stmt->execute();
                $count = $stmt->rowCount(); 
                if ($count >= 1)
                {
                    echo"Bezirk schon vorhanden";
                }
                else
                {
                $stmt = $handler->prepare("SELECT id FROM news_cat WHERE name = '$canton'");
                $stmt->execute();
                while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
                $parent_id = $row->id;  
                }


                $stmt = $handler->prepare("INSERT INTO news_cat(name,parent_id)VALUES('$name','$parent_id')");
                $stmt->execute();   
                }
        }

if ($text_line[0] != "")
        {
            $name = $text_line[0];
            $bezirk = $text_line[2];

                $stmt = $handler->prepare("SELECT id FROM news_cat WHERE name = '$bezirk'");
                $stmt->execute();
                while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
                $parent_id = $row->id;  
                }


                $stmt = $handler->prepare("INSERT INTO news_cat(name,parent_id)VALUES('$name','$parent_id')");
                $stmt->execute();   

        }

echo "<br>";
}

fclose($file_handle);


?>
```